# Shared MongoDb collection between two meteor apps deployed in amazon AWS not working.

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have deployed a meteor app to port `80` of my AWS instance using MUP. I deployed a second meteor app to port `3000`, but this time omitting mongo setup and specifying mongo url in the mup.js file. The setup works fine and the second app is deployed but none of my publications seems to work. I have tried the same setup with two test Apps previously and it worked.

MUP.JS of App 1

```
  module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: 'IP',
      username: 'ubuntu',
      pem: 'path to my pem file'

    }
  },

  meteor: {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    path: 'Path to my project',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
      docker: {

      image: 'abernix/meteord:base', 
    },
    env: {
      PORT: 80,
      ROOT_URL: 'base url/',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb:27017/dbname'
    },


    deployCheckWaitTime: 320,
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

MUP.JS of App 2

```
  module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: 'IP',
      username: 'ubuntu',
      pem: 'path to my pem file'

    }
  },

  meteor: {
    name: 'DashBoard2',
    path: 'Path to my project',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
      docker: {

      image: 'abernix/meteord:base', 
    },
    env: {
      PORT: 3000,
      ROOT_URL: 'base url/',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb:27017/dbname'
    },


    deployCheckWaitTime: 320,
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },


};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the connection to the database has been made? Typically the Meteor console will give an error if it can't connect to the MongoDB database. Also not sure if you have omitted your connection string, but it should be;

> mongodb://user:password@server:port/database